# Voice Typing special Functions

Tags: voice-command, voice-recognition

When voice typing, I know that you can say *comma* or *period* or *question mark* to get a , . or ?. Those were all in the android instructional video. But I just saw that you can say *new paragraph* and it will skip a line. I want to know if there's a list of these punctuation commands somewhere?